# Lua string.match() (Corona SDK)

Tags: string, lua, coronasdk, lua-patterns

Im trying to pull the auth code out of a server response like:

`GET /?state=authenticated&code=U946s9lHouBGWy8o45bXSRSXGzTqd0Ys HTTP/1.1`

I am using the lua/Corona;

```
string.match(request, "GET /?state=authenticated&code=([%w--_/.=?]+)")
```

I am getting a nil response and have no idea what Ive got wrong...anyone know or have a better idea?

wkr,

-sean

Comment: Is the auth code always just letters and numbers? It seems like you could use a simpler regular expression if so.

Comment: i think so.  I actually do not understand regex and got that snippet from another example but the example does the exact thing Im looking to do.  any help much apprecaited.  I guess I could just use anchorsearch or the like.  Im new to Lua too so not sure whats in the toolbox.  thx in advance Hunter

Comment: `request:match'&code=(%S+)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `?` on its own, acts as a pattern modifier. This is why you get `nil` result. Use a `%` to escape this.

```
str = "GET /?state=authenticated&code=U946s9lHouBGWy8o45bXSRSXGzTqd0Ys HTTP/1.1"

print( str:match("GET /%?state=(%w+)&code=(%w+)") )
```

Here is working output: https://eval.in/33065

---

### EDIT

Here is [another example](https://eval.in/33069) for the same, without escaping the `?` character. This is just to elaborate my point. :)

Comment: thank you so much hjpotter92, you nailed it.  Suggestions where I can learn what Im doing now?  :)

Comment: @user2467301 Lua uses patterns instead of normal regexes. You can use [Lua-Users wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial) or ask some basic queries in [#lua channel on irc](irc://irc.freenode.net/lua)

Comment: Patterns are carefully described in the [Lua reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1), and covered by most of a chapter in [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.1.html). They are powerful, but not as complete as the regex tools found in other places.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
string.match(request, "GET /%?state=authenticated&code=([^ ]+)")
```

Comment: thanks! I tired:local code = string.match(request, "GET /?state=authenticated&code=([^ ]+)")

Comment: but it comes back with code being nil.  I guess I must be doing something else wrong

Comment: @user2467301: see my edit. I haven't escaped the question mark

Comment: 3. `[^ ]` is not the same as `%S`. 4.Thanks for the EDI